# Why my div is not sliding up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

Why my Div is not sliding up ? Where i am doing wrong ?
here is my jquery details. Am I referring to correct url or somewhere i am having problem?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {
     var $fieldRevItems = $("#dvDetails");
     $('#<%=btnClose2.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
           $('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>').val('');
           $fieldRevItems.slideUp(600);
           e.preventDefault();
      });
  });
 </script>
```

and here is my html details(which is nothing but a div containing one table)

```
<div id="dvDetails">
        <table id="tblDetails" width="30%" style="border: Solid 3px #D55500; height: 100%"
            cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr style="background-color: #D55500">
                <td colspan="2" style="height: 10%; color: White; font-weight: bold; font-size: larger" align="center">
                    User Details
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    UserId:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    UserName:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblusername" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    FirstName:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtfname" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    LastName:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtlname" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    City:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" style="width: 100%">
                    Designation:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesg" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="width: 100%">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnClose2" runat="server" Text="Close" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: What errors does your console report?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the rendered code, but it appears to work: http://jsfiddle.net/xWqLy/

Comment: are you getting any errors? i usually set the ClientIDMode to "Static" on asp controls when i'm going to be using jquery and avoid <%= %>

Comment: btw i don't see your TextBox with ID txtSearch in your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector is fine. But, you not need to use $ for anything, you should:

```
$(function () {
 var fieldRevItems = $("#dvDetails");
 $('#<%=btnClose2.ClientID %>').click(function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>').val('');
       fieldRevItems.slideUp(600);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selectors appear to be the issue: `$('#<%=btnClose2.ClientID %>')` and `$('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>')`. Are you able to trigger any events based on those selectors?

The selectors referenced in your JavaScript should be those presented in your output source code. If you're attempting to pass a dynamic value from another language into the JS (as seems to be the case given your code), then you would need to either convert that value into a JavaScript variable to be passed into jQuery without quotes, or embed your JavaScript within the other language's template file, and then concatenate the echoed output directly as the jQuery selector.

Long story short, you're passing dynamic-looking code into jQuery as a string, instead of passing in a valid selector.

Comment: Those are asp.net code nuggets. The rendered `id`s don't always match the `id` in the source code, this is a way to work around it. Long story short, I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: I'm interested in that story, as the selector doesn't appear valid to me, and so I'm puzzled as to how this might function as a workaround. If the ids depend on asp.net, then that info should be passed into jQuery as a variable post transformation, rather than passed in here as asp.net code.

Comment: It's like php tags. You might see something like `$('#<?php echo $someVar ?>')`. The php tags don't actually make it to the rendered html/javascript, and neither does code between `<%=...%>`

Comment: Understood, and if that's the case then it's the same related issue. The value of the asp should be given to jQuery (not the asp as a string), which means either concatenating it into the JS and echoing the value (which isn't happening here), or outputting the asp into a variable and passing that in.